# ES6 Generator functions cause error: Uncaught ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined

Tags: ecmascript-6, elixir, phoenix-framework

If I put a generator function like

```
function* someWords() {
  yield "hello";
  yield "world";
}

for (var word of someWords()) {
  alert(word);
}
```

in app.js, the code produces an uncaught reference error.

If I run the same code from within a script tag in my app.html.eex, it runs fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code in `app.html.eex` will not be passed through babel. If you are using a browser that supports generators then they will work.

Since your `app.js` code is transpiled with babel, you will probably need to use https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/ for the generators to work.

---

`app.js`

```
import "phoenix_html"
import "babel-polyfill"

function* someWords() {
  yield "hello";
  yield "world";
}

for (var word of someWords()) {
  alert(word);
}
```

`brunch_config.js`

```
exports.config = {
  files: {
    javascripts: {
      joinTo: "js/app.js"
    },
    stylesheets: {
      joinTo: "css/app.css"
    },
    templates: {
      joinTo: "js/app.js"
    }
  },

  conventions: {
    assets: /^(web\/static\/assets)/
  },

  paths: {
    watched: [
      "web/static",
      "test/static"
    ],

    public: "priv/static"
  },

  plugins: {
    babel: {
      // Do not use ES6 compiler in vendor code
      ignore: [/web\/static\/vendor/]
    }
  },

  modules: {
    autoRequire: {
      "js/app.js": ["web/static/js/app"]
    }
  },

  npm: {
    enabled: true,
    whitelist: ["phoenix", "phoenix_html", "babel-polyfill"]
  }
};
```

`package.json`

```
{
  "repository": {},
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-brunch": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.3.14",
    "brunch": "^2.1.3",
    "clean-css-brunch": ">= 1.0 < 1.8",
    "css-brunch": ">= 1.0 < 1.8",
    "javascript-brunch": ">= 1.0 < 1.8",
    "phoenix": "file:deps/phoenix",
    "phoenix_html": "file:deps/phoenix_html",
    "uglify-js-brunch": ">= 1.0 < 1.8"
  }
}
```

Comment: i installed polyfill using `npm install -S babel-polyfill` but now I'm getting a new error in the web console: Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined. I put `import "babel-polyfill";` in app.js.

Comment: Have you added it to your whitelist in brunch-config.js?

Comment: I've tried adding the path "node_modules/babel-polyfill" to the paths but am not having any luck.

Comment: I think you just need to add "babel-polyfill" to the whitelist. https://github.com/phoenixframework/phoenix/blob/master/installer/templates/static/brunch/brunch-config.js#L68

Comment: i added `whitelist: ["babel-polyfill"]` to the npm section but am still getting the same error. When I click on it the console takes me to js that reads "if (global._babelPolyfill) {
  throw new Error("only one instance of babel-polyfill is allowed");
}"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101273/discussion-between-heartmo-and-gazler).